# ERROR ITMS - 90167 No. app bundles found in the package

Tags: xcode7, ios10, macos-sierra

Before I start writing about the error, I'm running on macOS Sierra and using Xcode 7.3.1.

So I'm creating an Archive from my App, I validate the App and it passes validation, but when uploading to App Store, I get the error "ERROR ITMS - 90167 No. app bundles found in the package".

[image]

I've checked all my documentation and I have everything.

- I have all my provisioning profiles.
- I have Release as "iOS Distribution".

This error just started appearing after I installed macOS Sierra.

Anyone has an idea of why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Same here - Sierra + 7.3.1.  Also can't run the simulator.  Regretting the upgrade... :-/

Comment: @JollyRoger I have no problems running in the simulator with Sierra Public Beta 1 + Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: @JasonFarnsworth. this error appears only in macOS Sierra Beta 1, not in macOS Sierra PUBLIC beta 1.

Comment: @CharlyPico I definitely encountered this exact error publishing to the App Store from Sierra Public Beta 1 + Xcode 7.3.1. I was able to use the simulator on the same builds, and I was able to publish a build (for testing) via Xcode 8 beta 3.

Comment: I got this error with Xcode 7.3.1 + macOS Sierra GM. Try using Application Loader didn't work too.

Comment: This is happening for me with the non-beta version 10.12 of Sierra and Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: Exporting with  Xcode 7.3.1 and submitting with  Application Loader from the Xcode 8.1 works for me.

Comment: This was happening to me with GM Sierra and XCode 7.3.1 - installing XCode 8 instead of 7.1 fixed it.

Comment: Using app loader from Xcode 8 solved the problem. Used Xcode 7.3.1 to export ipa file, and appLoader to upload.

Comment: This is happening on the non-beta version. Pretty shocking from Apple

Comment: @JollyRoger Is this Fixed Now I Have Following Versions. macOS - 10.12 xcode Version 7.3 (7D175) and xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a). and still facing the same issue

Answer (score 103, accepted):

After chatting with folks at WWDC in both the Xcode lab and the App Store lab, they were able to dig up information that this is a known issue in the current Sierra seed that is fixed in the next release.  You can either revert, or wait.  Not the most satisfying answer, I admit.

Comment: I identified a workaround: you can do your build in 7.3.1 and then push to the app store in 8 beta.  Until Sierra is fixed, this seems to be your best bet.

Comment: That sounds like a convincing answer to me, but I read it to late, I've just partitioned my Macbook Pro so 50 GB are for macOS Sierra and the rest to El Capitan. Thanks for the time.

Comment: @JollyRoger this worked for me, build with XCode 7.3.1 and upload using the Application Loader of XCode 8 beta. However still the message 'INFO ITMS-90111: "Beta Toolchain. This app has been built using beta toolchains. Apps built with beta toolchains are acceptable for TestFlight submission. Note that you will not be able to submit these builds for sale on the App Store."'

Comment: @JollyRoger you are a hero. Worked for me, although it failed on first attempt with some random error, but worked on next try.

Comment: What next release? I have the second Sierra release and this is still not working.

Comment: @Rob have you tested with the beta 3 of both macOS Sierra and Xcode that were released yesterday? Does that now work? Thanks.

Comment: @alpennec not yet, I am just installing both now

Comment: This appears to happen with the Public Beta 1 as well.

Comment: Still seeing this on the latest macOS Sierra Beta (4 I think)

Comment: Still the same on beta 5. I wonder if Application Loader 3.0 app is the Application Loader of XCode 8 beta you guys talking here about? I got very bad internet now and stacked downloading it, but have downloaded Application Loader 3.0 from Apple dev site. All I need is TestFlight now, no need to release before public versions appear.

Comment: UPDATE: Actually Application Loader 3.0 produces the same error.

Comment: Confirmed: Application Loader 3.6 (from XCode 8 beta) works as described!

Comment: Just to make sure this is clear for everyone, if you are receiving the "INFO ITMS-90111 Beta Toolchain" error, you can fix this by changing the build number of your operating system to a pre-beta build while you build the app from Xcode 7.3.1.  Then you can upload it with Application Loader 3.6 from Xcode 8 beta to fix the "ERROR ITMS - 90167 No. app bundles error" and then change the build back.  Credit to grgarside. The [link is here to show you how to change the build number and disable system integrity](https://georgegarside.com/blog/ios/submit-apps-built-beta-xcode/)

Comment: @JollyRoger Is this Fixed Now I Have Following Versions. macOS - 10.12 xcode Version 7.3 (7D175) and xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a). and still facing the same issue

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar Same here.. I eventually found the workaround by opening the .xcarchive file and upload via Xcode 8.

Comment: @FanZhang can you post steps to follow for the work arround

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar Open your Xcode 8, go to window - organizer, and upload your app from there instead of Xcode 7.x

Comment: @FanZhang I did tried both the way via application loader and also by organizer on both xcode 7.3 and 8 But failed

Comment: Biggest problem I am having is that after opening my project in Xcode 8, it updated all of my xib files. Now when trying to revert to Xcode 7.3.1 if messes up all of the xib files resizing properties.  I have the NON-Beta version 8 of Xcode, and I am still getting this versioning problem.  Using App Loader 3.6 I still cannot upload.  Anybody have advice BESIDES going backward and having to re-work all of my xib files?

Answer (score 46):

#### Problem:

- Issue with the current macOS Sierra build.

#### Workaround

- Build with Xcode 7.3.1 then upload using Xcode 8 [Beta]. (Thanks to @JollyRoger)
- Currently, this workaround **ONLY** works for **TestFlight** and **NOT** for **App Store** submissions.

#### No need for fix [UPDATE]

- So it seems that this bug has lasted for the whole beta period and it might not be worth for Apple to fix it anymore as the final version of iOS 10.0 is releasing in a few days and the final macOS Sierra is releasing a few days after that.
- If you are still getting this issue with the final build of macOS Sierra, make sure you are using Xcode 8.x and not anything earlier than that.

#### Possible errors:

1. **ERROR ITMS-90635**

   > ERROR ITMS-90635: "Invalid Mach-O Format. The Mach-O in bundle
   >   "....framework" isn’t consistent with the Mach-O in the main bundle.
   >   The main bundle Mach-O contains armv7(machine code) and arm64(machine
   >   code), while the nested bundle Mach-O contains armv7(bitcode) and
   >   arm64(bitcode). Verify that all of the targets for a platform have a
   >   consistent value for the ENABLE_BITCODE build setting."

   **Fix:** Uncheck the `Include Bitcode` option before uploading.
2. **INFO ITMS-90111**

   > INFO ITMS-90111: "Beta Toolchain. This app has been built using beta toolchains. Apps built with beta toolchains are acceptable for TestFlight submission. Note that you will not be able to submit these builds for sale on the App Store."

   **Note:** This will allow you to upload the build and use it for TestFlight but when trying to submit to the store you will be faced with this error message:

   > New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, OS X, and tvOS SDK. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta OS X builds.

Comment: Now getting this 'INFO ITMS-90111: "Beta Toolchain. This app has been built using beta toolchains. Apps built with beta toolchains are acceptable for TestFlight submission. Note that you will not be able to submit these builds for sale on the App Store."

Comment: This is not really an error. It is just letting you know that you cannot submit your app to the store. Did you Archive with Xcode 8 or Xcode 7.3.1?

Comment: I archived with Xcode 7.3.1 and upload it to ITC using Application loader from Xcode 8 beta, when I use that binary to submit the app to review, it failed with the error message stating, the builds with beta toolchains are not accepted for submission.

Comment: For the purpose of sharing information. I have also tried using custom open-source toolchains, uploading through Application Loader and iTunes Transporter command-line. None  of these worked unfortunately. Will update if I find a way.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Such a weird bug and I can't imagine what possibly changed to break Xcode like this.

https://i.imgur.com/Ydednlp.png

Comment: @Sarim You have to [change the OS build number when Archiving](https://georgegarside.com/blog/ios/submit-apps-built-beta-xcode/) to something that isn't a beta OS.

Comment: @grgarside Thanks, I'll try and will let you know.

Comment: @Rohan, glad I was able to help.

Comment: @xemacobra have you find any work around for the submission issue?

Comment: New macOS Sierra Beta 3 update doesn't allow uploading project. This answers is time consuming today.

Comment: No need for fix? Really?

Answer (score 39):

If you are uploading from Xcode7(less than Xcode8) and macOS Sierra(V10.12), So this issue **"ERROR ITMS-90167: "No .app bundles found in the package""** will come and will not allow to upload build to AppStore.

So use **"Application Loader V3.6" or "Xcode8"** to upload the build.

Comment: Have you try to submit an app with this way? If yes, any issues?

Comment: @Alex, I uploaded the app through "Application loader" and it is working fine for me.

Comment: The problem was not related to whether I used Application Loader or Xcode to upload. Only upgrading to XCode 8 solved the problem.

Comment: Any idea on why my Xcode 7 didn't show an update red circle on Apple Store desktop tray icon? I Had to enter Apple Store myself and search for Xcode in order to update it...

Comment: @pabitranjan From where we can download v3.6 of application loader? I couldn't find it any where in itunes connect.

Comment: @Sakkeer Hussain, Sorry for late response. Update Xcode to latest Version  (V8), Application loader v3.6 is build in tool with Xcode 8. Then you can see the from menu of Xcode app(Xcode --> Open Developer Tools --> Application Loader.

Comment: This worked for me. Was using xCode 7.3 (App Loader 3.5) with Sierra 10.12.1.
I downloaded xCode 8.3.2 with App Loader 3.6 and used the xCode 7.3.1 build to upload to App Store.
Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 24):

Try This, it worked like a charm for me,

We also facing same issues at time of updated **macOS Sierra**.

At time of upload build by using **Xcode7.3.1** we get an error message

```
 "ERROR ITMS-90167:"No.app bundles found in the package"
```

**To Solve Error And Upload IPA file On App Store Follow Below Steps**

- We export build by using **Xcode7.3.1**.
  [image]

-For upload build we use **Application Loader V3.6** of **Xcode8**.

Xcode -> Open Developer Tools -> Application Loader

**Follow Below Steps**

1) **Open Application Loader**
[image]

2) **Choose Build(IPA)**
[image]

3)**Uploading IPA file To app store**
[image]

4)**Successfully Submit Build(IPA)To App store**
[image]

Your App will uploaded on Appstore,

Hope this is help for some one.

Comment: This is the most correct answer. Uploading with Xcode 8 did not work for us but uploading with the Application Loader did.

Comment: Really works like a charm!, now I can go by that beer in the fridge... thx !

Comment: @SandroMachado . Great  :)

Answer (score 8):

I would first like to thank @xemacobra for his solution, it worked for me until I needed to submit an application for Review.

If you need to submit an application for the App Store, and the build says `You may not submit builds using beta software...` here is the solution:

The problem is Xcode is sending the build information along with the version of you Mac OS. To fix that, you just need to change your Mac OS build to an older, acceptable, version.

1. Restart your Mac and hold `Command + R` on boot up
2. Open Terminal
3. Run `csrutil disable`
4. Restart your Mac.
5. In Finder, go to `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist`
6. Open the file so that you may edit the `SystemVersion.plist`
7. Find `<key>ProductBuildVersion</key>` and locate the `string` attached to this `key`. For example, mine was `16A254g`.
8. Change this `string` to a version of Mac OS that is currently supported for public release. At the time of this solution this one will fine: `15G31`
9. Restart Xcode. Re-Archive your application. Re-Submit the application.

I did not try submitting the application through Xcode 7.3.1, but I do know this still works if you submit the `.ipa` through Xcode 8 beta 3.

Once you have submitted your build, revert the `SystemVersion.plist` to the original `string`, and repeat steps 1-4 replacing `csrutil disable` with `csrutil enable`.

Comment: CONFIRMED: Build/export with Xcode 7.3.1 and upload with 8 beta 3 APPLICATION LOADER and not organizer upload. Nice find

Comment: Well answer, I have just tried but you can add additional steps, after 4 If It doesn't allow give it write permission and change using terminal both build/version while opening system.

Comment: Shortly `csrutil disable` is not enough to write permission for me. I have tried this and successful after 4.step restarting `sudo nano -w /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist` Change ProductBuildVersion as `15G31` & ProductVersion `10.11.6` & ProductUserVisibleVersion `10.11.6` same. `Control-X` to save and then pressing `y`. Restart again Re-Archieve with XCode 7.3.1 pushed with 8 Beta `Application Loader`. Confirmed by Apple.

Answer (score 8):

I have also experienced the same. This is the simple way to solve your problem. `Archive` your app using `Xcode 7.3.1` and `export` the `ipa` file of your app into a directory by selecting the option `Save for iOS App Store deployment`.

After that open `Xcode 8.0` and open `Application Loader` from `Xcode` -> `Developer Tools`. Sign in to your team, and upload the `ipa` file using `Xcode 8.0`.

I have uploaded two apps to `iTunesConnect`, it will work for sure.

Comment: any help with that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39867313/installing-xcode-8-on-pre-installed-xcode-7-3-1-using-multiple-version

Answer (score 7):

I was having this issue with Xcode 8 GM and trying to submit an app for release though Application Loader.

You *have* to use the version of Application Loader that comes with Xcode 8, which should be 3.6

I still have Xcode 7 installed, and was using Application Loader 3.5

**Update**

- My apps submit okay now and go into processing, then soon after disappear completely. I think this might be a separate issue though.

**Update 2**

- You still can't use Sierra to submit your apps. At least not until they release the GM.

**Update 3**

- This issue is still occurring with this particular project. All other new ones (sticker apps) that I have created since public launch have been submitted to iTunes Connect with no issues.

I worked on this project during the betas, so it's possible something has been corrupted along the way and is causing issues. Might require starting a new project in Xcode 8.

There's a thread on the developer forums addressing this issue. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62703

## Solution

> Turns out the fix for us was to add the "NSCameraUsageDescription" key
>   to the info.plist with a description of what the camera does in the
>   app.

Not sure if that solution will help in all cases though.

Comment: "My apps now go into processing, then disappear completely. I think this might be a separate issue though." Same here. Have you solved this?

Comment: @DarkoDjuric Not yet. Other apps seem to be working besides this one though on the same system. Perhaps something went wrong at some point during the betas and the project is no longer any good. When I get a chance I'll create a new project and move the files across to see if it works.

Comment: Adding the NSCameraUsageDescription key to the app plist fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 6):

I submit an app built using LibGDX and had the same issue after upgrading to Sierra. I solved it by:

- Upgrading Xcode (8.x), as explained above
- Use the **latest version of appLoader (3.6). To do that, use the AppLoader available within Xcode**. I was using a standalone version of the appLoader: that's incorrect. Open Xcode and go to Xcode->Open Developer Tool->Application Loader

Comment: Best one, easiest one :)

Comment: This is the easy solution :) thanks. Apple is deploying unstable software. I have encountered a lot of problems with Sierra.

Answer (score 5):

Unable to process application at this time due to the following error: No .app bundles found in the package. This issues appear when your pc's space is less. So clear you trash or some useless document from you pc. Then let's try again! It's work for me!

Comment: Thank you! You saved my day as I was facing the problem in Big Sur and all other answers above are for Sierra.

Answer (score 4):

I recently upgraded to macOS Sierra and also received this error message. After uploading through the application loader failed.I downloaded Xcode 8 (**kept my 7.3.1 copy**). Closed Xcode 7.3.1. Opened Xcode 8-> Organizer-> proceeded to validate and upload my build. It worked. Hope this helps someone in a similar situation.

Comment: Glad it helped! I must have spent a day trying to figure it out

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's about your disk space check your disk space.

Answer (score 3):

Try open App Loader from Xcode8.
 **Xcode > Open Developer Tools > Application Loader**

Then you can upload app to TestFlight without the error.

Answer (score 2):

These are all fabulous answers above... follow Nicholas's 9 step process above and also Tobeiosdev if you don't have write access to the SystemVersion.plist file.

However be very careful about how you read the step by step guide. **DO NOT do as I did and restart your device after editing that plist file**, as you will render most applications on your mac useless, including Terminal & TextEdit (which are required to edit it back). Reopen terminal inside Sierra (or the beta OS you are running) not inside the command line.

---

I unfortunately found out the hard way and then could not edit the plist file again in the command line. So I then had to reboot several times before finding the solution which was to go into single user mode (Command-S on restart), all of which scared me senseless that I had ruined the build of my mac. Eventually got everything running again but was somewhat delayed too by having to reinstall Xcode 8... leading to a sleepless night as my first ever submission to the AppStore.

All in all, the above is a perfect solution that works all around, IF you follow the directions correctly. Lesson learnt!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem as follows, find your archive in the Organizer, and then:

1. Show in finder

[image]

2. Show package contents

[image]

3. In the „Wasabi.xcarchive“ file, find the
   „Products“-„Applications“-„Wasabi.app“(Wasabi is your app’s name),
   „Show package contents“ again

[image]

4. Finally, you can see there has a file named“Info.plist“, open it

[image]

5. Edit the value with a key named „BuildMachineOSBuild“, I just change
   it to „15F34″(it’s „El Capitan 10.11.5“ ’s version)

[image]

Comment: This approach works! I had updated my OS to 10.11.6 (15G1108) today and was getting the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally opened an old version of the Application Loader Version 3.5 (921) and got the error ITMS-90167 no app bundles found. Be sure you open the Application Loader over the menu of Xcode (Xcode->Open Developer Tool). Version 3.6 (1020) works like a charm! :)

Comment: Life saver. How come Application Loader 3.5 was the default when using latest macOS and Xcode was a mystery, and worse was that the error message wasn't explicit at all. Using version 3.6 resolves it all.

Answer (score 1):

According to @Fan Zhang answer follow these steps and you can upload this archive use Xcode or Application Loader, whatever you want!

When you archived your app, find your archive in the Organizer, and then:

```
-->"Show in finder";
-->"Show package contents";
-->In the "xx.xcarchive" file, find the "Products"->"Applications"->"xx.app"(xx is your app's name), "Show package contents" again;
-->Finally, you can see there has a file named"Info.plist", open it;
Edit the value with a key named "BuildMachineOSBuild", I just change it to "15F34"(it's "EI Capitan 10.11.5" 's version);
```

Answer (score 1):

With me, my application writing by `Swift 2.2`. And must use `Xcode 7.3.1` to `archive` and upload to `Apple testflight` but got the same error(I run on `macOS Sierra-10.12`). The follow solution fix it for me, hope another who face the same problem can find somethings helpful:

```
1> Use Xcode 7.3.1 to archive
2> Export to file .ipa
3> Quit Xcode 7.3.1 then open Xcode 8, and then open Application Loader, use Application Loader to upload file .ipa to itunes connect.
```

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps, I had the same error code `"ERROR ITMS - 90167 No. app bundles found in the package"` using `mac OS 10.14.4` with `Xcode 10.2`.

(As a note, I was able to successfully submit builds some weeks ago with the same configuration, but this seems to be something in the iTunes Connect side)

Had to update to `mac os 10.14.6` and `Xcode 10.3` to successfully submit my build.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem .
what worked for me was ->

go to  target-> signing & capabilities -> signing certificate -> I had to revoke one certificate. Always revoke the Certificate by the name of admin's iMac .
It is created by default while making your certification and profiles.

**Picture is attached for the reference.

PS:- always make sure the bundle id is same on App store connect and Xcode before archiving.[image: after I revoked, I was able to upload the build.]

Answer (score 0):

The privacy settings are changed for iOS 10, more on this could be read [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/privacy-settings-in-ios-10/)

I had previous described issues, which had to be solved as described, but after successful upload application wasn't visible on iTunes connect.

I had to add `Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description` key in a plist in order to solve the last one. 
Other missing keys will make the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error with Xcode 7.2.1 and Application Loader 3.4 on macOS 10.12.1.

But for some reason, it worked if I used the command-line "altool" to do the upload instead:

```
'/Applications/Xcode-7.2.1.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Versions/A/Support/altool' \
  --upload-app -f your-app.ipa \
  -u your-apple-id -p your-apple-id-password \
  --output-format xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to provide missing application name in order to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go inside your Appstore and download the new version of Transporter.
this worked for me