# XCode: No .app bundles found in the package

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, macos-sierra

I have installed the latest OS: macOS Sierra(from App Store) and I have XCode 7.3. I am trying to upload my 1st app from Organizer. I have created all the distribution, development profiles. But, still I am getting the above error. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: make sure you have appropriate bundle id matching the certificates/provisional profile .

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan They are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Mac OS Sierra issue. Build with Xcode 7.3 and then upload with Application Loader started from Xcode 8.

More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838487/error-itms-90167-no-app-bundles-found-in-the-package).

Comment: If you feel that this question is a duplicate, flag it as such.  Please don't post links to other Stack Overflow posts as an answer.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Quite a terrible bug.