# ERROR ITMS-90167: "No .app bundles found in the package"

Tags: ios, xcode, .app

So I've been working on a new project for a while, and I've finally decided to archive and upload it to the App Store. It all seemed to be working good, until I got this error that doesn't seem to go away no matter what I try:
[image]

I have been having this problem for the last couple of days now, and trust me, I've tried everything everywhere. I have gone to every other Stack Overflow question related to this one, and their answers aren't working for me.

- I am set to release as iOS distribution
- I disabled bitcode
- I have all my provisioning profiles

And, in my project here shows:

[image: I do have a .app file]

I do have a .app file.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I don't know if this is important or not but it was stated in other questions, but I am using macOS Sierra with Xcode 7.1.1.

EDIT: You can ignore the iTunes Store operation problem :)

Comment: you can see this info [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838487/error-itms-90167-no-app-bundles-found-in-the-package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838487/error-itms-90167-no-app-bundles-found-in-the-package)

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838487/error-itms-90167-no-app-bundles-found-in-the-package