# Installing Xcode 8 on pre-installed Xcode 7.3.1 [Using multiple version]

Tags: xcode8, xcode7.3, macos-sierra, xcode-command-line-tools

Hi I am currently using **Xcode 7.3.1** on **macOS Sierra**. Due to the issue ERROR **ITMS 90167**. I can't upload my archive using **Xcode 7.3.1**. So, It's time to upgrade **Xcode 8**.

But, unfortunately, I can't use **Xcode 8** to Develop application due to migration problem on my previous project which was big. All I want is built in Application Loader from **Xcode 8**. And I need to do some migration on Xcode 8 while I am developing my current app from **7.3.1**

**`And I did download Xcode 8 from Developer Program => Xcode8.xip`**

Before I install this version, I changed my previous **Xcode 7.3.1** to

```
//Application/Xcode7.3.1.app
```

inorder to protect overwriting this version.

When I paste **Xcode 8(Xcode.app)** which i extract from .xip to Application Folder, I open it after its done installing after passing "Installing Component".

Then I open it,it worked **(Xcode.app) = Xcode 8**.

Then when I open my **7.3.1(Xcode7.3.1.app)**, it stop working means can't open and show me crash message every time I opened it until I changed my **Xcode 8** app title to

```
//Application/Xcode8.app
```

So, there will be two Xcode Version on Application Folder. Then when I open **Xcode 8(Xcode8.app)**, it won't let me open and show me error alert again.But, **Xcode 7.3.1(Xcode7.3.1.app)** come back to live and prompt me to install `.git` `Command Line Tools` then I can work back using **Xcode 7.3.1**.

But then, my problem is I can't open or use **Xcode 8** anymore even I change my Xcode app name to different name.Was it "Command Line Tools" causing the problem?

I really need solution to solve this case because I want to use both Xcode Version on my mac.Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Xcode DMG files. I have `Xcode 7.3.1` in my `Applications` folder and `Xcode 8.0` in my `Desktop` folder. I use both Xcode very often.

---

If you already have two `Xcode` delete one, delete `Xcode 8.0`. Or delete both of them if you want. And you can download `Xcode 8.0` from developer portal or update to `macOS Sierra` and download the `AppStore` version of `Xcode 8.0`. But then you can't download `Xcode 7.3.1`, you will not get the `DMG`, I don't think that you can download the `DMG` from developer portal for `Xcode 7.3.1`.

So in my opinion the best option is that. delete `Xcode 8.0` from your `Applications` folder. And download `Xcode 8.0 DMG` from developer portal and put in some other folder not in `Applications` folder.

Comment: So I don't need to add Xcode 8 to Application Folder from what u answered.

Comment: Ok, for now, I wrongly deleted my Xcode8.xip. Now, I am downloading and gonna try yours. If work out, I would love you click Correct Answer. If it doesn't work out, I will let you know. Thanks

Comment: @6245Htarwara Download Xcode 8 DMG and put it in your Desktop folder, and keep Xcode 7.3 in Applications folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have both the versions of Xcode 7.3 and 8.0. I have installed Xcode 8.0 from dmg file without changing anything in the applications folder for Xcode 7.3.1.

After installation of Xcode 8.0, I observed application folder has only one Xcode version so to open projects in different version I do something like in the image

[image]

This works just fine.