# "ERROR ITMS - 90167 No. app bundles found in the package" Error

Tags: xcode, application-loader

I want to send my app to the AppStore with Application Loader. However, I am getting this error all the time. How can I fix this?

My Mac's Version: macOS Sierra 10.12 Beta

My Xcode's Version: Version 7.3.1

The error is

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me:-

1. export the ipa for Xcode 7.3.1
2. Close Xcode 7.3.1 and open Xcode 8
3. Use Application Loader of Xcode 8 to upload the ipa

this question might be a duplicate of [ERROR ITMS - 90167 No. app bundles found in the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838487/error-itms-90167-no-app-bundles-found-in-the-package)

However among the many solutions there, this is what worked for me.