# How to fix No App Bundles On XCode Version 12.4 (12D4e)

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I have a problem uploading my testing IOS .ipa on the app store, so right now after the uploading process, there is an error pop up that **Error ITMS-90167: "No .app bundles found in the package.**

**Library Use:**

React Native: Latest Version

This is quite new and interesting to me, it is my first time to encounter this error.
Can anyone help me with this kind of error and how to solve this kind of error?

Hope someone helps me to fix this.

[image: Error Found]

Answer (score 0):

More likely this issue related to certificate or your current Xcode version.

Here what you can do:

1. Open Target -> Signing&Capabilities -> Signing Certificate -> Uncheck and check again (this will update your entitlements).
2. If 1st doesn't work for you. Try to update it to latest XCode 13.1 and upload again.

There is similar question opened for Xcode8 with workaround, that could help you too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37931353/4977439

Comment: Oleg Thank you for your suggestion I hope this very well helpful :)

Comment: Did it work for you? @DevGe